# Forbidden 403 error when running apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am trying to set up a rails app(redmine) on Ubuntu 14.10 running apache2.

log

> Cannot server Directory: No matching DirectoryIndex
>   (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found,
>   and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

host.confg

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin kanishka@thewolf.in
  ServerName app.in
  ServerAlias app.in
  DocumentRoot /var/www/app.in/public_html/
  ErrorLog /var/www/app.in/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/tribeapp.in/access.log combined
  <Directory  /var/www/app.in/public_html/redmine/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Require all granted
    RailsBaseURI /redmine
    PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

New to rails. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Server configuration issues are more on-topic on http://http://serverfault.com/, SO is for programming issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options All <--turn on all options
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks   <--- replace previously set options with these two
```